# Change description in flyway migration filename

Tags: flyway

I have a flyway migration script named `V1_7__a_and_c.sql`, but I realized that it wasn't about "a" and "c", but actually about "a" and "b", so the proper name for that file is in fact `V1_7__a_and_b.sql`.

Can I just rename this file, or are there consequences that may cause problems in the future?

Answer (score 1):

If you rename the file, you should manually patch up the metadata table as well to avoid any validation errors.

Comment: Do you mean I should create another file (i.e. V1_8) or that I should do this completely manually? The latter isn't an option, since it was pushed to a shared repository, meaning the file is in use by several developers, the automated build system and possibly one or more demo environments. I'd be sure to miss something.